# Moment is not defined when using React with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, momentjs

I'm in the progress of "Reactifying" a PHP application and am adding a single component to start (with several child components). In addition to the custom components, there are several library dependencies (react-bootstrap, moment, etc).

I'm using webpack to compile it and it compiles correctly and generates the `dist/main.js` as expected. **However, when adding it to the HTML template I get the error "moment is not defined"**, though the "react-bootstrap" dependencies appear to load correctly. Based on the guidance in https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/959, I tried both `import * as moment from 'moment'`, `import moment from 'moment'` as well as the `const moment = require('moment');` I had previously been using which compiled fine with browserify.

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components'),
    entry: './dir/EntryComponent.app.jsx',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.json', '.js']
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

*Component.jsx*

```
import Collapse from "react-bootstrap/Collapse";
import moment from 'moment';
const Datetime = require('react-datetime');
...
<label>Start</label>
<Datetime
   value={this.props.startDate}
   placeholder="Start Date"
   dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
   timeFormat={false}
   input={true}
   viewDate={moment().subtract(1, 'month')}
   onChange={date => this.props.updateStartDate(date)}
   closeOnSelect={true}
   closeOnTab={true}
   viewMode="months"
   inputProps={{readonly: 'readonly'}}/>
```

Comment: Did you do `npm install moment`?

Comment: Yes, `"moment": "^2.25.0"` is in my `package.json` and is installed

Answer (score -1):

use npm install moment to install moment
Then you can import it with "import moment from "moment";"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but those steps were already done (per the comments/question above)